# Data table is not generated when I attempt to add a connection

Tags: database, model-view-controller, code-first, scaffolding

I'm following a guide for creating a simple code-first MVC, which uses data context scaffolding.  After creating a model class file and adding a scaffolded item to the project, it instructs me to go to server explorer, hit "new connection", enter (localdb)\mssqllocaldb and from there, select my database name (PlanetContext (CodeFirstFinal.Models).  After hitting "ok", I should be able to expand the tables in my server explorer and see the planet data table.  However, my tables folder is empty.  I followed the tutorial to the letter, so I'm unsure why this is happening.

Here is the code in my model:

```
namespace CodeFirstFinal4.Models
{
    public class Planet
    {
        public int PlanetID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class PlanetContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Planet> Categories { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As this is a very simple app, this is the only code so far, besides the scaffolded view. (For that, I right-clicked my project, selected "add scaffolded item" and MVC 5 Controller with views using EntityFramework.  I then entered my model class, which is:
Planet (CodeFirstFinal4.Models)

and my data context class, which is:  PlanetContext (CodeFirstFinal4.Models).

I'm not sure how helpful this information is, but I'm including it in case it helps.  I'm pretty sure that the MvcScaffolding package is installed correctly, as well as EntityFramework.  However, I simply can't get the data table to be generated after right clicking 'connect to database' under server explorer, entering my local server name, and selecting the database.  Below is a screenshot of the tutorial, where his table shows up under the tables folder, within server explorer.  Does anyone know what might be causing the failed generation of my own data table?

[image: data table in tutorial]

Comment: Did you generate an entity framework migration using `Add-Migration` and then applied it to the database using `Update-Database` console commands as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#generating--running-migrations)

Comment: @lmantas  Thanks for the tip! I enabled migrations, added a migration and ran the update-database command, but the table is unfortunately still not showing up.

Comment: Did you refresh the database/table list in your server explorer after that?

Comment: After that, I repeated the step of adding the connection, typing my sever name and selecting the database. Sorry I forgot to mention that part!  The table folder showed up again with no table inside. Is that what you meant by refresh? Is that something else?

Comment: Did you provide the same connection string to migrations as the one you use in server explorer?

Comment: @lmantas Sorry for the late reply!  I am ashamed to say that didn't occur to me, as the guide I followed didn't mention anything about a connection string.  I'm going to look into that now.